# ext4 filesystem still has errors after fsck

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, ext4, bad-blocks

Suddenly my ext4 file system fell down into read-only mode.
I've unmounted this disk and tried to repair it, but without any success.

1. `fsck` tries to fix something but ends with `FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED`, `WARNING: Filesystem still has errors`.
2. `mount` fails with `failed: Structure needs cleaning` message.
3. `badblocks` tool shows several errors.
4. `smartctl` test status: `read failure`.

Also, I've made disk image via `ddrescue` tool, but can't repair/mount partition from it as from HDD.

What I want:

1. Mount partition and copy not damaged files.
2. Make decision - does this HDD has physical problems, or this is only ext4 crash?

Answer (score 1):

If the `badblocks` tool shows several errors and `smartctl` is reporting errors, then it indicates you definitely have some kind of HDD problem.  So you need to address that first.

The most conservative thing you can do is to use `ddrescue` to get two disks that are at least as big as your hard drive.   I'm going to call your original disk `ORIG`, and the two disks `DISK_A` and `DISK_B`.   First use `ddrescue` to make a copy from `ORIG` to `DISK_A`.   Then use `ddrescue` to make a copy from `DISK_A` to `DISK_B`.  Why make copies right away?   Because if your hard drive is failing (and your report that `badblocks` shows errors is a strong indication there are errors), you want to make a copy right away before more sectors fail.   (Sometimes hard drives have cascade failures where initially it's only a handful of sectors that go bad; but then more and more sectors can start going bad if the problem was due to a head crash kicking up debris into the sealed chamber, and then when debris impacts the heads, they crash into the platters again, damaging more sectors, and kicking more debris... repeat until the disk is dead as a doornail.)

Why make a second copy from `DISK_A` to `DISK_B`?   Because you'll try various recovery techniques on `DISK_B`, and if they end up causing logical damage, you can always go back to `DISK_A`, and copy the original disk image on `DISK_B` (or maybe even `DISK_C`) so you can always have a fallback in case a particular recovery technique makes things worse or you hope that some other technique might recover more data.

It is likely that `e2fsck -fy` will be able to completely fix the file system image on `DISK_B`.   If it can't, it's likely a bug in `e2fsck`.   Please see the `REPORTING BUGS` section of the `e2fsck` manual for more information about what is needed for a useful bug report.  (Also give information about your hardware and what you've done to rule out hardware problems --- making a copy of the file system image to new disk is a great way of doing this.)

Comment: Theodore, I've made an image (via `ddrescue`) and tried to repair (`fsck`) it. But no luck. Was it valid action?

Comment: Stack exchange is probably not the right place to be discussing this, because there's not enough room for all of the details necessary to figure out exactly what you've done.   Did you follow *exactly* what I suggested above?    Can you make a copy of the initial copy, and then run fsck on the copy, saving the output to a file and sending the output to the linux-ext4@vger.kernel.org mailing list?

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the file recovery:

1. Make disk image via `ddrescue`.
2. Open it via `DMDE` tool and copy files.